# Como faço para mostrar o texto de uma notificação quando o usuário abrir esta notificação?

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging

Estou criando um app com o PhoneGap e usando o `cordova-plugin-firebase` para enviar notificações ao Android, estou conseguindo enviar a notificação, porém, quando "abro" a notificação não consigo mostrar o conteúdo dela (título e mensagem)

```js
window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(notification) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(notification));
}, function(error) {
     console.error(error);
});
```

Tudo o que aparece no alert são:

```
google.sent_time
google.ttl
tap
from
google.message_id
google.priority
collapse_key
```

conforme a imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém sabe como posso pegar as informações e exibi-las ao usuário?

Comment: Provavelmente vc vai usar o collapse_key ou o google.message_id para buscar a mensagem desejada.

Comment: Mas como eu busco, isso que não estou encontrando, vi em alguns vídeos que ela vem junto na notificação, porém imprimo no alert e não aparece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui, na verdade o problema não estava no app, e sim onde envio a notficicação, com o FCM preciso enviar titulo e mensagem para quando o app esta em foreground e outro para quando está em background, só estava enviando do foreground, entao quando recebia notificação com o app aberto aparecia, mas não com o app fechado, ao abrir pela notificação não aparecia, resolvi enviando assim

```
"to" : "<DEVICE TOKEN>"
, 
"notification": {
    "title": "This is used in the foreground",
    "body": "This is used in the foreground"
},
"data":{
      "title":"This is used in the background",
      "body":"This is used in the background"
}
```

conforme esse link
https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/431